# mousePressEvent() not called on a disabled QCheckBox

Tags: c++, qt, qcheckbox

I'm trying to subclass `QCheckBox` to make it pass mouse clicks through if disabled. When my checkbox is not disabled (`isEnabled()` is `true`), Qt calls its `mousePressEvent()` as expected. When it is disabled, calls do not happen. Any ideas how to outmaneuver it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is indeed the documented [behavior](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop). If you look at the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp), you will see that `QWidget::event` only calls `mousePressEvent` if the widget is enabled.

As a solution, you may override `event` instead of `mousePressEvent(QEvent *e)` and check if `e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress`.